# Is it possible to sort anki review cards by tags?

Tags: anki

Let's say I have a deck named "Main" with two subdecks: "One" and "Two". All cards from subdeck "One" have either "A" or "B" tag and all cards from subdeck "Two" have either "C" or "D" tag. When I want to study, I use the Study now button from the "Main" deck so that cards from both subdecks are included.
The first thing that was bothering me was that cards from "One" and "Two" were getting mixed so I fixed that by setting new card gather order for "Deck". So now cards from "One" are shown first and then cards from "Two".
Now another problem is that cards with "A" and "B" tag are getting mixed (same with cards with "C" and "D" tag) and I don't know how to fix that.
The order of review cards display I would like to achieve is:
cards with "A" tag scheduled for the day (in random order)
cards with "B" tag scheduled for the day (in random order)
cards with "C" tag scheduled for the day (in random order)
cards with "D" tag scheduled for the day (in random order).
The thing is that e.g. "A" and "B" cards refer to completely different topics so it's not cofortable for me to review them at the same time.

as I explained above